# If heliosphere refracted light, would stars appear further away?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

If the heliosphere (including heliosheath) had a higher refractive index than interstellar space, would objects outside it appear to be smaller and further away?

[image]

Comment: The answer you recived to [your first question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519921/520) contains an analytic solution. Why not just calculate?

Comment: This is a collaborative platform. So, just if there is anyone else interested in it. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

No.  When you look through a lens system at something that is magnified or reduced, you're mapping one region onto one of a different size.

As an example, when you look at the full moon in your binoculars, you might map the 0.5 degree moon into 10 degrees in your visual field.  Of course this comes at a cost.  The other objects in that 10 degree region are obscured by the image.  If you magnify one region, that must come with a reduction or obscuration of some other region.

But in the center of a uniform optical system, all regions are identical.  If none are special, then there can be no magnification.   It would be like trying to enlarge all the details on a globe without making the globe larger.

The answer could be different if you weren't at the center.  Being toward one side would introduce an asymmetry that would allow magnification in one direction but not the other.  But the heliosphere is large enough that shouldn't be a consideration for us.